# New to Laravel - Route does not work

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I just started learning Laravel from this series: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/2

I use windows 10 with Wamp.

My site sits under: sites/highland.lar

I created the virtual host.

The route has this code:

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
```

When I go to: http::highland.lar I get the page: Index of/ instead of the Welcome.blade.php view.

I added an index.php file to the root folder to test, and this file works fine.

After installing laravel the public/htaccess looked like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Reading this link: [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls)
I changed it to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Nothing helps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just realized if I add public to my url it works. So what do I need to do to make it work without the public?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved the problem with this link:
[enter link description here](http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/)